# how change defaultCalendarForNewEvents objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, eventkit

I want to save the event in my selected calendar but the function `setcalendar:calendarWithIdentifier()`  works only since ios5 and i want to support ios4, therefore I need to change `defaultCalendarForNewEvents` on device with objective-c.

Please give me a hand!

Comment: Question edited and waiting for review. iOS4.